# Can I insert comma into numbers? The numbers are parts of strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to do like this. Do you know a good way?

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample = "eventA 12:30 - 14:00 5200yen / eventB 15:30 - 17:00 10200yen enjoy!"
    i_want_to_generate = "eventA 12:30 - 14:00 5,200yen / eventB 15:30 - 17:00 10,200yen enjoy!"

    replaced = re.sub("(\d{1,3})(\d{3})", "$1,$2", sample)  # Wrong.
    print(replaced)  # eventA 12:30 - 14:00 $1,$2yen / eventB 15:30 - 17:00 $1,$2yen enjoy!
```

Comment: Will there ever be numbers with more than 3 digits that you don't want to insert commas into in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the correct notation for your back-reference(s). You could also add a positive lookahead assertion containing the currency to ensure only those after the `'yen'` are changed:

```
replaced = re.sub(r"(\d{1,3})(\d{3})(?=yen)", r"\1,\2", sample)  # Wrong.
print(replaced) 

# eventA 12:30 - 14:00 5,200yen / eventB 15:30 - 17:00 10,200yen enjoy!
```

Comment: Wow, I had to use "\1" instead of "$1"! I was wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\1` instead of `$1` for substitution

Check: https://regex101.com/r/T2sbD2/1

Comment: This web site is useful. Thank you very much.